# update column in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table `test`

```
Id ParentId DisplayingOrder GrpId 
1  NULL        NULL         NULL
2  NULL        NULL         NULL
3  NULL        NULL         NULL
4  NULL        NULL         NULL
```

I need to have something like that :

```
    Id ParentId DisplayingOrder GrpId 
    23  NULL       1            21
    24  NULL       1            22
    25  NULL       1            23
    26  NULL       1            24
```

I tried this

```
; WITH CTE 
AS
 (
 SELECT [Id],[ParentId] , [GrpId],DisplayingOrder 
        ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY [ParentId] ASC) RN1
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [ParentId] ORDER BY [ParentId]) RN2
  FROM [dbo].[test]
 )
UPDATE CTE 
SET  [GrpId]         = RN1
    ,DisplayingOrder = RN2
```

But it returns as result :

```
      Id ParentId DisplayingOrder GrpId 
        23  NULL       21            1
        24  NULL       22            1
        25  NULL       23            1
        26  NULL       24            1
```

Comment: How about swapping the definitions of `rn1` and `rn2`?

Comment: Just interchange rn1 and rn2

Comment: Are you sure of what you want? Reading the query the result you got is right, the GrpId is calculated by the Dense_Rank and the DisplayinOrder by the Row_Number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this section swap `RN1` with `RN2` :

```
SET  [GrpId]         = RN2
    ,DisplayingOrder = RN1
```